# Overload operator[] in std::array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdarray

I would like to optimize my code overloading the bracket [ ] operator in std::array, which I use everywhere subtracting one. The code compiles but never calls the overloaded function, could anyone tell me why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
class A
{
    std::array<int,5> var{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::array<int, 5ul>::value_type& operator[](std::size_t p_index);
};

std::array<int, 5ul>::value_type& A::operator[](std::size_t p_index)
{
    return var[p_index - 1];
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a.var[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Code returns "1" but I would expect "0".
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That code would not compile, which means it does not produce the output you describe.    `main()` is trying to access the private member `var` of class `A`, but is not a `friend`.

Comment: `public:` missing in the snippet and it should be `a[1]` as `var` is of type `std::array`

Comment: Aside - this is generally considered bad practice because in 6 months when you look at it again, you'll wonder why a[0] doesn't return the first item.  Rather than pass around a 1 indexed id; why not make it 0 indexed; and then you don't have to subtract 1 everywhere?

Comment: In C++, indexing starts at 0, not 1.  Why go against what every C++ programmer knows?  Trying to fake 1-based arrays will more than likely lead to very hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not "overloading" subscription operator `[]` for your array; you are rather defining your own subscription operator for class `A`, which will be invoked on instances of `A`, but not on instances of A's data member `var`.

So you need to write...

```
std::cout << a[1] << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
0
```